# Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compileSdk()

Tags: java, android, gradle

Hello Guys i have this Problem Here with android studio , here is my sdk Installed :
[my sdk installed except those 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgarG.jpg)

I got a problem like that :

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compileSdk() for arguments [30] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compileSdk() for arguments [30] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

My `build.gradle` file :

```
android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Net.er.bate.accel"
            minSdk 19
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `Version` part of the `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` variables.

Try updating your `build.gradle` file to the following and see if it works.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Net.er.bate.accel"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: still shows me this error : Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compileSdk() for arguments [30] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: 16:15 Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compileSdk() for arguments [30] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension. (1 m 49 s 506 ms)

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Net.er.bate.accel"
            minSdk 19
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).